# Сделать выборку с условием из таблицы

Tags: excel

У меня есть задача,нужно из базовой таблицы создать другую на основе заданных условий.
Я изучаю excel пару дней,но немного знаком с программированием. В общем, моя идея - использовать какую то функцию,которая возвращает номер строки,удовлетворяющей условию. И в новой таблице мы получаем массив данных по номеру и разбиваем его на ячейки. В общем,хрень какая-то и вряд-ли это можно реализовать.
Нашел функцию ИНДЕКС `=ИНДЕКС(B2:B51;ЕСЛИ(И(E2:E51="м";H2:H51="АПС");B2:I2;"")`но ничего не работает. Понимаю,что функция "если" возвращает массив ячеек - строку. Но что с ней делать дальше? Ее запихать сразу  в таблицу, в отдельную строку?В общем, не понимаю. Помогите пожалуйста.Вот текст задачи [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В надстройках есть Power Query? Если есть воспользуйтесь им (и если по заданию это не запрещено). Выделяете всю таблицу, выберите в меню Power Query "Из таблицы или диапазона". Откроется редактор, там сможете задать нужные вам фильтры. Сначала по мужчинам, затем повторите процесс с фильтрацией по женщинам. После, откройте редактор PQuery и выберите в правом углу кнопку "Объединить" (Полное внешнее объединение). После чего можете удалить первую или вторую отфильтрованную таблицу, оставив только одну объединенную. После добавления новых строк в исходную таблицу, они будут появляться в новой.

Answer (score 1):

Какому воспаленому мозгу понадобилось собрать такие разношерстные данные? :)

Чтобы не городить массивные формулы, нужно перед выборкой отметить нужные строки.

В отдельном столбце формула:

```
=--ИЛИ(И(E2="м";H2="АПС");И(E2="ж";I2>=3000;I2<=8000))
```

Единичками отметятся строки для выборки. Фильтровать, копировать видимые, вставить на другой лист.

Если же по условию, которое в задаче - результат разместить на том же листе (что, с точки зрения размещения и хранения данных, неправильно), нужным строкам присвоить идентификаторы - последовательную нумерацию.  Для этого левее таблицы вставить столбец (это будет столбец `А`), вписать в `А2` и протянуть по строкам формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(E2="м";H2="АПС");И(E2="ж";I2>=3000;I2<=8000));МАКС($A$2:A2)+1)
```

На другом листе формула для выборки (не забываем, что данные сместились вправо):

```
=ВПР(СТРОКА(A1);Лист1!$A$2:$J$99;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1);0)
```

В эту формулу желательно добавить проверку на максимальный номер строки. Но и это, и создание таблицы условий, и таблицы результата - это уже сами. Подсказки и справка по функциям Вам в помощь (задание-то вам дали...)